# Mockito.doNothing() keeps returning null pointer exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I know I should not be testing void methods like this, but I am just testing Mockito.doNothing() as of now with a simple example.

My Service class:

```
@Service
public class Service{
    @Autowired
    private Consumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer;

    public void clearSubscribtions(){
        kafkaConsumer.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

My Test class:

```
 @MockBean
 private Consumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer;

 @Test
 public void testClearSubscriptions() {
     Service service = new Service();

     Mockito.doNothing().when(kafkaConsumer).unsubscribe();
     service.clearSubscriptions();
 }
```

The test keeps failing with a null pointer exception. When I debugged it, it goes into the clearSubscription method of the service class, and there on the line of kafkaConsumer.unsubscribe(), kafkaConsumer is null. But I mocked the consumer, why is it throwing null pointer exception and I should be skipping over that method, right?

Edit:
All the declarations of the class:

```
@Autowired
  private Consumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer;

  @Autowired
  private Service2 service2;

  private final Object lock = new Object();

  private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Service.class);

  private HashMap<String, String> subscribedTopics = new HashMap<>();
```

Figured out what was wrong, I needed to auto wire the service

Comment: Because I assume that the field to mock is never mocked. You seem to mix Spring, and Mockito. Can you show all the declaration of the class. I think that the problem is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are instantiating a new service `Service service = new Service();` but from what I can see you are never injecting the mock bean into the new service.

Here is a sample of what I think you could do if you are using mockito only and dont need to instantiate a spring container (used a single class for ease of example dont do this in actual code):

```
package com.sbp;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) // run with mockitos runner so annotations are processed
public class MyServiceTest {

    public interface Consumer<T, R> {

        public void unsubscribe();
    }

    @Service
    public class KafkaConsumer implements Consumer<String, String> {

        @Override
        public void unsubscribe() {
        }

    }

    @Service
    public class MyService {

        @Autowired
        private Consumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer;

        public void clearSubscriptions() {
            kafkaConsumer.unsubscribe();
        }
    }

    @Mock // tell mockito that this is a mock class - it will instantiate for you
    private Consumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer;

    @InjectMocks // tell mockito to inject the above mock into the class under test
    private MyService service = new MyService();

    @Test
    public void testClearSubscriptions() {
        service.clearSubscriptions();
        Mockito.verify(kafkaConsumer, Mockito.times(1)).unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

If you need an example via Spring using MockBean or without and dependencies, let me know and I can post.

UPDATED:  adding sample using spring junit runner and using spring boot's mockbean annotation

```
package com.sbp;

import com.sbp.MyServiceTest.TestContext.MyService;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) // run with spring
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyServiceTest.TestContext.class) // make it a spring boot test so @MockBean annotation is processed, provide a dummy test context class
public class MyServiceTest {

    public interface Consumer<T, R> {

        public void unsubscribe();
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class TestContext {
        @Service
        public class KafkaConsumer implements Consumer<String, String> {

            @Override
            public void unsubscribe() {
            }

        }

        @Service
        public class MyService {

            @Autowired
            private Consumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer;

            public void clearSubscriptions() {
                kafkaConsumer.unsubscribe();
            }
        }
    }

    @MockBean // this will create a mockito bean and put it in the application context in place of the Kafka consumer bean defined in the TestContext class
    private Consumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer;

    @Autowired // inject the bean from the application context that is wired with the mock bean
    private MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void testClearSubscriptions() {
        myService.clearSubscriptions();
        Mockito.verify(kafkaConsumer, Mockito.times(1)).unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also note,  I just created a dummy Consumer class cause I did not have the actual class in my environment

Comment: Is there a way to run this with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class. If I run it with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner, I get application initialization error if I change from MockBean to Mock for Consumer because the Consumer is AUTOWIRED in the service class

Comment: I added a sample using  SpringJUnit4ClassRunner in combination with SpringBoots @MockBean annotation.  You will have to adapt to your environment/configuration

Comment: Why did u introduce @Configuration?

Comment: I needed to tell the spring boot test where to look for the beans required for the example.  Most spring boot applications have a class @SpringBootApplication annotation somewhere that will be found when the test is launched.  The test example did not so I had to sort of fake it.

Comment: forgot to auto wire the service. Thanks